# Entered wrong installation path in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I was trying to install Huwaie 3G modem on Ubuntu. The install.txt said:

> 1. Run `./install` in TERMINAL to install MobilePartner
>      eg: # bash //install
> 2. If you had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "The software is exist, do you want overwrites? ([Y]/[N])", enter "y" to overwrites or "n" to exit.
> 3. If you do not had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "Please input the install path[/usr/local/Mobile_Partner]:". Then you can input install path(fullpath), or you may using the default path(/usr/local/Mobile_Partner) by press ENTER direct
> 4. Finish installing
>
> --How to run--------------------------
>
> - From shortcut in desktop
> - Run MobilePartner in your install path
>     eg: # `/<install path>/MobilePartner`

But accidentally I gave it

1. Run `./install` in TERMINAL to install MobilePartner
   eg: # bash //install
2. If you had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "The software is exist, do you want overwrites? ([Y]/[N])", enter "y" to overwrites or "n" to exit.
3. If you do not had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "Please input the install path[/usr/local/Mobile_Partner]:". Then you can input install path(fullpath), or you may using the default path(/usr/local/Mobile_Partner) by press ENTER direct

The path `/usr.local.bsnl3g`. Now the software is not getting installed. I was trying to make fresh install (by `./install`) but it prompted me to rewrite in the same {wrong} path where I have installed already.

How to proceed to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

#### Re-run

Most of these installers can just be re-run and re-installed. I would rerun the installer and specify the correct path the second time.

If the installer doesn't do a decent job of cleaning up you can always manually remove files afterwards too. I would remove that directory `/usr.local.bsnl3g` as well.

#### ./install is a script

Additionally you could check to see if the `./install` script/application takes any command line arguments. Try looking at it using the command `more install`. If it's a text based script you can see exactly where it's installing files and manually back them out yourself using `rm`. Use caution when doing this and make sure you're only removing the files that this installer installed, and nothing more!

#### ./install is a exectuable

If the installer is an actual exectuable you could see if it takes any command line options. Typical ones are as follows:

```
$ ./install -h
$ ./insatll -help
$ ./install --help
```

Also you can get executables to give up their usage by giving it bogus switches too:

```
$ ./install -howdoirunyou
```

Comment: I deleted the /usr/local/bsnl3g and one more  created by it and tried running ./install. Following is the result:
The software is exist. Do you want overwrite it? ([Y]/N):y
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/bsnl3g/BSNL_3G’: No such file or directory

Can not create dir: /usr/local/bsnl3g/BSNL_3G

Finished, press any key to exit

Comment: @Girish - can you see if the installer wrote a dot file out? ls -la where the installer is for starters.

Comment: @sim There is no dot file, I searched in /home and in /usr/local

Comment: @Girish - and what about the nature of the install app? Is it a shell script or an exectuable?

Comment: @sim I think its shell script since more install option shows the file, but to ./install I have to make it executable. Also ./install -h does not show any option.

Comment: @Girish - Yes making shell script exectuable is different than an actual binary that's executable. Could you post the install script on pastbin.com and post the link here so I could take a look at it?

Comment: I have shared it here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2-qmYKmaAtgaXZ1TEJLNVE1djg/edit?usp=sharing